# Converting mySQL query to Laravel 5 with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, multiple-conditions

I have this kind of mySQL query. I'm using for this to  search with license_id, email(of user), machine_id

```
SELECT license.license_id, license.instances, license.expiry_date,license.license_type, users.email 
FROM license 
INNER JOIN purchase_items ON purchase_items.license_id = license.license_id
INNER JOIN customer_purchases ON customer_purchases.customer_purchase_id = purchase_items.customer_purchase_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = customer_purchases.customer_id
INNER JOIN machines ON machines.license_id = license.license_id
WHERE customer_purchases.status = 1 
AND license.license_id LIKE '%9fe%' 
OR users.email LIKE 'hora%' 
OR machines.machine_id LIKE '%dfd3%' 
GROUP BY license.license_id
```

Here I started this to write in Laravel 5 like this

```
     $key = $request->search_key;         
    if(($request->session()->get('user'))!=null){           
                                    $license_data = License::join('purchase_items','license.license_id','=','purchase_items.license_id')
                                    ->join('customer_purchases','customer_purchases.customer_purchase_id','=','purchase_items.customer_purchase_id')
                                    ->join('users','users.user_id','=','customer_purchases.customer_id')
                                    ->where('customer_purchases.status','=',1)
                                     //some more codes                        
                                    ->groupBy('license.license_id')                                   
                                    ->select('license.license_id', 
                                            'license.expiry_date', 
                                            'license.instances', 
                                            'users.email', 
                                            'license.license_type',
                                            'license.is_valid')
                                    ->paginate(10);
```

I can't understand how to use multiple conditions.

($key means search keyword coming along with the url )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$license_data = License::join('purchase_items','license.license_id','=','purchase_items.license_id')->join('customer_purchases','customer_purchases.customer_purchase_id','=','purchase_items.customer_purchase_id')->join('users','users.user_id','=','customer_purchases.customer_id')->where('customer_purchases.status','=',1)->orwhere('license.license_id','LIKE',$key)->orwhere('users.email','LIKE',$key)->orwhere('machines.machine_id','LIKE',$key)->groupBy('license.license_id') ->select('license.license_id', 'license.expiry_date', 'license.instances','users.email',  'license.license_type',license.is_valid')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "orWhere" condition.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#where-clauses

For example:

If $key is array and contains licence_id,email and machine_id,
Then query is

```
$license_data = License::join('purchase_items','license.license_id','=','purchase_items.license_id')->join('customer_purchases','customer_purchases.customer_purchase_id','=','purchase_items.customer_purchase_id')->join('users','users.user_id','=','customer_purchases.customer_id')->where('customer_purchases.status','=',1)->orwhere('license.license_id','LIKE',$key['licence_id'])->orwhere('users.email','LIKE',$key['email'])->orwhere('machines.machine_id','LIKE',$key['machine_id'])->groupBy('license.license_id') ->select('license.license_id', 'license.expiry_date', 'license.instances','users.email',  'license.license_type',license.is_valid')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: $key is not an array. It just carry a word like this `url?search_key=01090434e8f850779c6670be` . I have to search that word whether it matches to machine_id, license_id, emai(user). I did like this. but no result. $license_data returns empty array